# How to check, and then, pull out part of list's item?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make equipment system in my game in Python3 and it generally works well, but I have small problem with countable values - while normal items can be storaged separately, things like money definitely not. I made the script for adding them, but the one thing is still missing.

So, let's say we have a list:

```
chest = ["500 $","shotgun","book","whatever else"]
```

And the question is: how to check the `chest` list to find if there's any `$` in it, and then, pull out the value before `$` character (in mentioned example, `500`)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't even consider storing items like that. There are countless better options available to you, like a dict of `{item: quantity}` pairs: `{'$': 500, 'shotgun': 1, 'book': 1}`.

Comment: I would like to store it that way, but for now I'm a bit newbie at writing in Python3 and I don't know how to mix using dictionaries with other equipment mechanics I used so far. So I will try to make it that way in the future, but for now I wanted to have at least well-working mechanics for one item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a list comprehension, it is as simple as:

```
>>> [int(item.strip(' $')) for item in chest if '$' in item]
[500]
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, this works perfectly well and it's more simple than I expected this to be!

Comment: @Shadow glad it worked :) Could you please also accept this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, for your game make a Chest class, with money and items attributes:

```
class Chest: 

    def __init__(self,money,*items):
        self.money = money
        self.items = list(items)

    def add_item(self,item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def add_money(self,money):
        self.money+=money
```

Then you can initialize a chest with an amount of money and items

```
chest = Chest(500,'cat','gold bar','sword')
```

You can access the money amount with `chest.money`. You can access the items with `chest.items`. You can add an item:

```
chest.add_item('aardvark')
```

To see it, run `chest.items`. You can add 200 dollars similarly with `chest.add_money(200)`.

Object oriented programming : )

Comment: I knew about this option, but I already used mechanics for adding and removing any item (so we can use chests to find items, but also for storing our things in them) - and I would need to change it significantly to implement what you mentioned. Anyway - it's great idea, so I will keep it in mind for future remaking mechanics, of course :)